# Multiple tables side by side in repeater

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, html-table, repeater

Just wondering if anyone can suggest a way to better implement what I am doing with the following markup?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGames" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description:</td>
                        <td>Start time:</td>
                        <td>End time:</td>
                        <td>Game type:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Is there a better way of achieving my desired output?

Comment: PS: I am aware this will create 1 row and I will need 2 scroll. This is my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code  will create one row and you may have to scroll horizontally to see all items

Try to do it using `div`s something like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptGames" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
  <div class="lists">
</HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description:</td>
                    <td>Start time:</td>
                    <td>End time:</td>
                    <td>Game type:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
   </div>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Add these classes to your `CSS` file

```
.lists
{
left:0;
width: 900px;
    list-style: none;
}
.lists div
{
display:inline;
float:left;
margin-left:20px;
margin-bottom:30px;
width:280px;
}
```

you can adjust values of margin , padding, and width according to your design

Comment: Thank u! I guess thats about the only other way of doing it but not sure its any better then my approach.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be to use the DataList and put the table in the item template and set the number of columns to 2 or however many you wanted to appear in a row.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Description:</td>
                <td>Start time:</td>
                <td>End time:</td>
                <td>Game type:</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("Description") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("StartTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("EndTime") %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("GameType") %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```